# sql server: using coalesce to check if character exists and replace it

Tags: sql-server, coalesce

How I can use `coalesce` to check if a variable (`@var`) is ',' and if so replace it with '' (empty string)?

Something like the reverse of:

```
coalese(',','')
```

So if `@var = ','` then I want `@var = ''`

But if `@var = 'a,b'` then I dont want it changed -> `@var = 'a,b'`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

Comment: Why would you want to use `COALESCE` for this? It should better be `CASE WHEN @var = ',' THEN '' ELSE @var END`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coalesce is specifically for handling NULL.. maybe use the replace function?

```
replace(field,',','')
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql

for something more specific you can use case:

```
case when field = ',' then '' else field end
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

for a variable:

```
set @var = case when @var = ',' then '' else @var end
```

Comment: this will replace ',' with ''. I want to replace it only if ',' is the only character contained in @var

Comment: @aggicd the question isnt' clear. `COALESCE` has nothing to do with *replacing* anything. And if you want to check for equality, there's no replacement either. Just a check for equality and an assignment

Answer (score 1):

Coalesce is use to check null values only.

You can use case statement for this :

```
select case when col_name=',' then '' else col_name end as col_name
```